# Upgrade to Nx13 missing styles

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade, angular13, nomachine-nx

After upgrading to Nx13 (angular 13) from 12, my library lost all styles,
meaning when I run the storybook, it seems like the scss file are not imported with the components themself.

when I try to pack the lib and install it in my main app, the scss files are there, but i keep getting the error `SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.`

my guess is that the same problem is happening in the storybook, but I just don't see the error itself, anyone faced this issue? any idea to what can cause it?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your options in angular.json?

```
options: {
  ...,
  styles: ["your stylesheet"]
```

Can you post your build or serve settings?